# Declare size of a vector inside class

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to declare the size of a vector inside a class. I want the vector size equal to another attribute of this same class. Vector **"table"** is inside the class **Hashtable**. **"bucket_count"** is the intended size for the vector **"table"**. the error given is **"member is not a type name"**. Please let me know what another way I can declare the size of a vector inside the class. If not, then what is the way out? Thanks.
Please refer to the code below.

```
class HashTable {
public:
    int bucket_count;
    vector<list<string>> table(bucket_count);
    //bool isEmpty(list<string> &cell) const;
    int hashFunction(const string& s);
    void insertItem(string value);
    void removeItem(string value);
    bool searchTable(string s);
    void printTable();
    void processQueries();
    void processQuery(const Query& query);
};
```

Comment: `vector<list<string>> table(bucket_count);` declares a function returning a vector with an unnamed parameter of type `bucket_count`, and  `bucket_count` is a member variable, not a typedef, hence the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete.This explains my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be

```
vector<list<string>> table{(size_t)bucket_count};
```

Comment: But when, where or how is the value of `bucket_count` determined?

Comment: The members of a class are initialized by order they are declared in the class body. In his case is doesn’t initialize the count so it would be never, but if he initialized it in the constructor initialization list (before the body), it will be used correctly.

Comment: I fixed the error in an edit. The {} syntax is rather new so it doesn’t allow the old c implicit int to uint conversion.

Answer (score 2):

I tried making a constructor which worked for me, but I am not sure why it worked.

Here is my code:

```cpp
HashTable::HashTable(int bc)
    : bucket_count(bc)
    , table(bucket_count)
{}
```

In this, the **bucket_count** is initialized to bc in this constructor which is agreeable. But by that logic **table** should be initialized to **bc**. But that is not what happened. Instead the size of table vector got initialized (which is what I wanted).

If anyone could explain, why the constructor initialization worked this way it would be of great help.

Comment: Incidentally, the members are initialized in the order **in which they are declared** not in which they are given in the initializer list - doesn't matter that much, in your case, but it's worth noting!

Comment: The order of items in the initializer list should match the order of their declaration. They will always be initialized in the order of declaration and thus having a different order in the initializer list can lead to confusion. If you turn on compiler warnings the compiler will let you know.

Comment: @AdrianMole `Long Hand` maybe. Cleaner and more maintainable yes.

Comment: When you are starting it is worth increasing the warning level your compiler uses to as high as possible. Fix all warnings as if they are errors (as they are errors in your logical thinking). Warnings usually result in issues if you are new so best to try and remove them. If you are using g++ and clang  `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror` If you are using DevStudio you can go into the project configuration and raise the warning level to 4 (default 3 (last time I looked)).

Answer (score 1):

This depends largely on how, where and when you set the actual value of `bucket_count`. For example, you *could* set the size of the `table` vector in the initializer list of your class constructor. The following code lets you do this by setting the size in the constructor call, either by passing a size explicitly when you construct a class object, or by using a default value (`42` in the code I've shown):

```cpp
class HashTable {
public:
    int bucket_count;
    vector<list<string>> table;
    HashTable(int bc = 42) : bucket_count(bc), table(bucket_count) { }
//...
```

Alternatively, if `bucket_size` is to remain constant and universal, you could make it a `static constexpr` member:

```cpp
class HashTable {
public:
    static constexpr auto bucket_count = 42;
    vector<list<string>> table;
    HashTable() : table(bucket_count) { }
//...
```

Comment: I am new to C++. Could you please let me know why you wrote "table(bucket_count = bc)" in the constructor? This way it seems as bucket_count is an attribute to "table" whereas bucket_count and table are both attributes to HashTable.

Comment: So,  you mean "HashTable(int bc = 42) : table(bucket_count = bc) { }" initializes bucket_count = 42 because of "bucket_count = bc" statement and then goes on to initialize the size of "table" vector = 42. Please let me know if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @MartinYork Thanks - but it was deserved. My original answer was decidedly 'lazy' (and also, as it happens, caused the OP some unnecessary confusion). Your comment was most helpful.